Why does my program started from a bash script get stopped when the script is backgrounded, but only when it gets stdin from a named pipe?
As described in the title, I am trying to run a program from a bash script, but it is getting stopped when I background the script. However, this is only the case when I redirect its stdin to a named pipe and keep the pipe open from the same script.
Here is a minimal reproduction of the behavior:
In foo.sh I have:
#!/bin/bash
while true
do
    echo "Running"
    sleep 1
done

In bar.sh I have:
#!/bin/bash
rm -f pipe
mkfifo pipe
./foo.sh < pipe &  # Let's say foo.sh has PID 42
cat > pipe 

In the shell I run ./bar.sh, which repeatedly prints "Running" as expected. Then I background bar.sh and it stops printing. If I run kill -CONT 42 it starts printing again.
However, if I don't redirect stdin to the pipe (i.e. replace ./foo.sh < pipe & with just ./foo.sh &), when I background bar.sh it does not stop printing.
Can someone explain this difference in behavior to me, and if possible explain how I can prevent foo.sh from stopping when it gets its stdin from the named pipe?

Likely a duplicate of Linux process in background - "Stopped" in jobs? and see backgrounded job keeps stopping

@DavidC.Rankin, those do seem similar, but the answers all seem to describe a stoppage resulting from the background process trying to read from its session's terminal.  That's not what is happening here with the OP's foo.sh.  It's stdin is not connected to the terminal, and it doesn't try to read from stdin anyway.

At least, not directly.

I would have been inclined to say that foo.sh gets stopped because it's in the same process group as bar.sh (which it was in my tests), but that does not explain the dependency on whether its stdin is connected to the pipe or to the terminal, which I can reproduce.  I note, however, I do not reproduce being able to continue foo.sh once it stops, except by bringing the whole job back to the foreground.

cat > pipe tries to read from stdin and write to the pipe.

I think Barmar nailed the sequence of events that leads to the background job being stopped in his answer. I know I've run into this issue on more than one occasion. Any I/O from a backgrounded process that affects any of the standard streams is touchy. I'd have to test, but I'd certainly try redirecting on another file descriptor and see if that makes any difference with the pipe. I also have to admit I've never chased this issue to ground. Generally being in a hurry I've just worked around it in another way..... humans....

Sorry @JohnBollinger is correct, I can't continue foo.sh without bringing the whole job to the foreground. That was from a previous version of the script I was testing where I had cat pipe & instead of ./foo.sh < pipe &, in which case I could continue the stopped cat program. I've edited the question to reflect this.

cat > pipe tries to read from stdin, so it gets stopped when it runs in the background.
The reason this doesn't happen when you don't redirect the input of foo.sh to the pipe is that the shell is blocked trying to open the pipe for writing. That won't succeed until another process opens it for reading, and it doesn't start cat until it opens the pipe.
When I reproduce the error, ps shows that both foo.sh and bar.sh are in T (stopped) state:
    PID TTY      STAT   TIME COMMAND
1888904 pts/1    T      0:00 /bin/bash ./bar.sh
1888907 pts/1    T      0:00 /bin/bash ./foo.sh
1888908 pts/1    T      0:00 cat
1888924 pts/1    T      0:00 sleep 1

So it appears that the entire process group is being stopped, not just the cat process.
The symptons are different on MacOS than Linux. On the Mac, I get the following error when I put bar.sh in the background:
cat: stdin: Interrupted system call

and Running keeps on printing. I don't know if this is due to OS differences or the older version of bash.

This makes sense, but the answer would be more complete if it explained why foo.sh also gets stopped when bar.sh tries to read stdin while in the background.

Huh ok I understand what you're saying about cat > pipe not running until the read end is opened, but I don't get why foo.sh stops running once that happens: if I don't redirect foo.sh's stdin to the pipe, and then background bar.sh, it keeps printing up until I run cat pipe in another shell to open the read end. Why doesn't foo.sh continue running in the background even though cat > pipe is stopped? I feel like I'm missing something fundamental about backgrounded jobs here. Could you elaborate on the first part of your answer?

I can't reproduce the problem of foo.sh stopping.

@Barmar here is the sequence of events that causes it to stop for me. The contents of foo.sh are the same as my original question, and bar.sh has the ./foo.sh < pipe & line replaced with just ./foo.sh &.
In shell 1 I run ./bar.sh, then background it. At this point foo.sh is still running. Then in shell 2 I run cat pipe to open the read end. At this point foo.sh stops printing.

I'll retry on Linux, to see if it's different from MacOS.

OK, I get your failure on Linux. ps shows that all the processes are in T state.

I've updated the answer.
